# Integration testing with White

Tags: winforms, testing, integration-testing, white-framework

Has anyone got experience with the white framework?

[www.codeplex.com/white](http://www.codeplex.com/white) ?

I'm thinking about using it for the next project for basic smoke tests of our windows client. I'd like some advice on articles or your own experiences. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I recently used white to build a few (20+) UI tests for a fairly complex WinForms app with plenty of UserControls, dynamically created and 3rd-party controls.

Here are my impressions:

- Very easy and intuitive to work with.
- Little or no quality issues.
- It's a young project so there are
  some missing features, but they've
  got the basics covered.
- Occasionally, if a control didn't have a known AutomationID, I was forced to use keystrokes to navigate to and manipulate a control ("tab, tab, enter" for example) which was kind of a bummer, but still very easy to do in white.  This usually only happened with 3rd-party or dynamically generated controls.
- White's recorder is helpful (and will actually generate code for you) but does often get confused by complicated or unusual controls.  For that reason I'd recommend that you...
- ...keep UISpy nearby so you can see the AutomationID of the controls you're working with.
- And finally, if you're like me, you're hoping to set up some automated tests.  This can be tricky since an automated test will usually be run by a CI tool such as CruiseControl which runs as a Windows service, which therefore has no active graphical environment (Windows session)...which white requires.  The [suggested](http://www.codeplex.com/white/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Using%20with%20Continuous%20Integration&referringTitle=Home) way around this is to use a virtual machine.  This is where I lost steam, as my tool chain had just grown too large for my purposes: CruiseControl->NAnt->NUnit->white + virtual machine.

Anyway, hope that's useful.

Comment: I'd also add that the documentation is extremely poor at the moment, so it's not as easy as it could be. Hopefully it'll end up being documented here ;)

Comment: Regarding running the tests on the build server, an option I have used is to use windows auto-logon (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231) feature, so that the server is running a graphical windows session.

Answer (score 0):

I evaluated it recently, but had to reject it because it would not support the third party controls (janus grid) we were using.

Comment: did other testing tools work with the janus grid?

Comment: We recently started using Ranorex and it seems to work great. http://www.ranorex.com/