# Switching from Web UI testing to Windows Forms application testing

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, selenium, automated-tests

I have been using Selenium (WebDriver) for some time now, utilising Microsoft Team Foundation Server (VS2010, Microsoft Test Manager, Lab Management) to trigger my automated tests on specified builds. This has been working great and I have even written a wrapper framework to allow for a lot of re-usability and switching to WatiN should it be needed.

My issue is, now the applications I am to test are Windows Forms (with infragistics and Teecharts), not Web Applications, and I am under the impression from my research that both Selenium and WatiN will now be inappropriate. I have been reading about NUnitForms and White as they appear to be common free choices amongst SO posts asking a similar question. However, I am wondering if anyone has had experience with setting up TFS with automated UI tests for a Windows Forms Application?

Or, failing that, has anyone used Visual Studio 2010 with a free Windows Forms UI testing package and had some success? My plan is to try White/NUnitForms next week, but though I would look for some personal recounts just in case this is not worth pursuing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more reading and checking around SO, I have found a few more helpful links. I am still at a loss as to a solid way to do things but am confident it can be done.

The following links I found helpful; [winforms Post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71746/integration-testing-with-white), [Continuous Integration in White Documentation](http://white.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20with%20Continuous%20Integration&referringTitle=Home) (I missed this initially somehow...), and as a further look I found utilising NUnit with White TFS is fully supported for my needs. NUnit with TFS can be found [here](http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/).

Hope this helps anyone in the same position, and I welcome any further answers as I still have not commenced any actual testing.

EDIT:
Have decided to use White with NUnit as NUnit has a lot of documentation with results integrated with TFS and White is somewhat of a wrapper to Visual Studio's Automation Tools.